# How to make an animated additive SVG Mask?

Tags: css, svg, masking, clipping, animated

**Hello!**

I am no good Coder but a Visual Artist so I made a graphic to explain my project a bit.

http://imgur.com/OlllSyz

In the Image you can see my setting.

**I want to achieve** that the webgl background is only visible by the pattern layer masks.
And these are moving and shall be additive when overlapping (like in the graphic shown at the bottom) but masking as well. (I dont mean the blend mode at this part)

Here you can see what i mean by pattern and my state so far:

http://www.kevinbock.de/webgl/index.html

The black pattern elements which are moving shall mask the Background and dont mask each other. So basicly: all black elements shall let through the webgl background. And instead of masking each other they shall add together.

At the moment no masking is added because I dont know how to do that.

**Now here are my questions:**

How do I make the three layers as masks which add to each other as they overlap?
Do I need the svg masking or css masking or the path clipping ?

At the moment I am using three single svg files.
Do I need to add some mask commands to the svg files or to some html part or/and css?

The movement of every pattern layer is achived by animating css and the div they are in.
Does it matter for making masks additive?
Or should all three pattern layer be in one svg file and be animated there with the svg animations?

Do I need a fifth layer between the webgl layer and the first pattern layer which is a fullscreen black rectangle to mask the pattern out from and let the webgl layer shine through?

Comment: +1: For one neat maze-runner like welgl animation (hope I'd be an artist next life :)

Comment: and i hope i get this thing to work like i want to :D
and thanks ;)

but credits for the webGL goes to this guy: http://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/kqtrz

i want to develop it further visually